# Why I can't delete data in cascade way?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cascade

The problem is when I want to delete user I'm getting error in Spring Boot like that:

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`32506632_pam`.`badge`, CONSTRAINT `FK4aamfo6o0h5ejqjn40fv40jdw` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))

I'm guessing that I need to delete data in cascade way. So I've placed *CascadeType.REMOVE* value to *@OneToOne* annotation like that, but it doesn't work:

**badge entity**

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "badge")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Badge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "badges", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Reader> readers;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    private String number;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private byte[] photo;
}
```

**user entity**

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastname;

    private String pesel;

    private String email;

    private String telephone;

    private Integer age;

    private String gender;
}
```

**reader entity**

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "reader")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Reader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Badge> badges;

    private String department;

    private String room;

    private Boolean status;
}
```

**Class which loads initial data**

```java
@Component
public class DataLoader implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BadgeService badgeService;

    @Autowired
    private ReaderService readerService;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        User user1 = new User(null, "Jan", "Kowal", "11111111111", "jan@kowal.pl", "+48111111111", new Integer(23), "male");
        userService.saveUser(user1);

        Reader reader1 = new Reader(null, null, "Warehouse", "207A", new Boolean("true"));

        Badge badge1 = new Badge(null, Arrays.asList(reader1), user1, "738604289120", null);
        badgeService.saveBadge(badge1);

        reader1.setBadges(Arrays.asList(badge1));
        readerService.saveReader(reader1);
    }

}
```

**Endpoint for deleting user** - it uses repository which extends CrudRepository and uses default delete behavior.

```java
@DeleteMapping("/deleteUserById/{id}")
private void deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    userService.deleteUserById(id);
}
```

**Database structure in phpmyadmin**
[image]

My goal is to delete user and associated badge with him, then to delete row in reader_badges table.